# Async on loading DOM elements (in loop) doesn't work as expteced

Tags: loops, asynchronous, dom

i'm trying to make an explorer-like in js. I created a class Explorer who load in the DOM a div (explorer) in a parent, then load in the DOM a div2 (repertory) in the div1. Then, with a knowed repertory, i need to load in DOM divs into div2 (repertory) asynchronously not to block the rest.

i trying to do it but it doesn't work as i described, the divs are all loaded at once so it block the other actions. We should see the red div (div1 : explorer) then the blue div (div2 : repertory) and then the divs loaded one by one.

can someone help me ?

I did this codpen to illustrate, it's a sipmlified code.
The Button symbolize the other actions i want to do during process.
*(
Go to line 54 then change the array on which the loop is performed to understand my problem.
)*

https://codepen.io/DragoLeForgeron/pen/yLKLeqm

```
class Explorer {
  
  parent;
  rep1;
  rep2;
  
  constructor(){
    this.parent = document.getElementById("parent");

    this.rep1 = [/*some object data*/];
    this.rep2 = [/*same as rep1 except that he's bigger*/];

    this.loadExplorer();
  }
  
  
  loadExplorer() {
    
    // Load explorer in parent
    let explorer = document.createElement("div");
    explorer.id = "explorer";
    explorer.classList.add("Explorer");
    this.parent.appendChild(explorer);
    
    // Load repertory container in explorer
    let repertory = document.createElement("div");
    repertory.id = "repertory";
    repertory.classList.add("Repertory");
    explorer.appendChild(repertory);
    
    this.loadRep().then(() => console.log("do some stuff after"));
  }
  
  
  async loadRep() {
    
    // Try to use rep2 instead of rep1, you will see that the explorer and repertory will be load after going through the rep (btw it's the same for rep1 but we feel it less)
    await this.rep1.map(async entry => {
      
      // Load div
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = entry.name;
      div.classList.add("Entry");
      div.innerText = entry.name;
      
      await document.getElementById("repertory").appendChild(div);
    });
  }
  
}

let explorer1 = new Explorer();
```

thanks by advance for help.

Comment: Algorithms made through loops and array methods allow you to replicate `rep1` so you don't have to make a hard coded array of a 1000+ lines. Also, you can't have duplicate ids, they must be unique. One more thing, what is the advantage of slowing down the loading of the DOM? I can't think of any reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks for replicate method, i use it know.
The ids are not the problem, moreover this is just an example.
Can you retry my codepen and change to rep2 at line 54 to illustrate my pb ?